# Samsung Galaxy S4 but no BluetoothAdapter?

Tags: android, bluetooth, galaxy, samsung-mobile

I tried establishing a Bluetooth connection via Unity in 2d configuration on Android.

Therefore i wrote a plugin calling

```
BluetoothAdapter btad = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
```

but when i execute this on my Galaxy S4 the adapter is null, so this would mean that there is no Bluetooth adapter. I'm now a little bit confused why this happens and how to solve it...

Even

```
btad=(BluetoothAdapter) getSystemService(BLUETOOTH_SERVICE);
```

is not working.

Btw: I tested the plugin and it works, but the bluetooth connect-method returns that the adapter is null...

The Class-code is

```
import java.util.List;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;

public class Btconnector extends Activity {

private static final int REQUEST_ENABLE_BT = 267;

boolean bton;
BluetoothAdapter btad = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();

public boolean connect() {
    btad = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
    if(btad==null)
    {
        btad=(BluetoothAdapter) getSystemService(BLUETOOTH_SERVICE);            
    }
    if (btad != null) {         
        if (!btad.isEnabled()) {
            bton = false;
            Intent enableBtIntent = new Intent(
                    BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
            startActivityForResult(enableBtIntent, REQUEST_ENABLE_BT);
        } else {
            bton = true;
            listcon();
        }

        return true;

    } else {
        return false;
    }
} //[...]
```

Comment: Did you enable blutooth on your device?

Comment: Try : getSystemService(String) with BLUETOOTH_SERVICE. from http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothAdapter.html

Comment: Yes, I enabled bluetooth, but normally this schouldn't be the problem, because i can activate it with the plugin.

As you see in the last code i did the getsystemservice thing already

Comment: Did you read the docs?  I think you might be using the old method.   Try getSystemService(String).

Comment: Tried it now this way:

`public boolean connect() {
  //btad = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
  btad=(BluetoothAdapter) getSystemService(BLUETOOTH_SERVICE);
  
  /*if(btad==null)
  {
      
  }*/
  if (btad != null) {   
   if (!btad.isEnabled()) {
    bton = false;
    Intent enableBtIntent = new Intent(
      BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
    startActivityForResult(enableBtIntent, REQUEST_ENABLE_BT);
   } else {
    bton = true;
    listcon();
   }

   return true;

  } else {
   return false;
  }
 }`

Comment: "when running on JELLY_BEAN_MR2 and higher, retrieve it through getSystemService(String) with BLUETOOTH_SERVICE"

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothAdapter.html

Comment: Also don't post code in comments.  Not helpful.  Edit your question if you feel it's relevant.

Comment: As i told (and showed) you i used also getSystemService - result is the same - but maybe it is a permission problem - i try to solve it this way...

Comment: Did you get a solution to this?

Comment: @OverMind I can not remember that I solved the problem. Possible that there was some permission missing, but i have no solution in mind (anymore).